# Accidental clicks on admob ads

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I have accidentally clicked on admob ads on my unity android game while testing. It has summed up to $0.54 will it make an issue later on? If yes what can i do to resolve it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is related to a specific third party issue that needs to be taken up with that third party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ever never. Continuous clicks on ads by same user many times result to violation and Admob account gets suspended . So in your case, never happen(if you didn't clicked ads many times). For that you can use dummy data by testing in emulator.

```
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

    // Add a test device to show Test Ads..comment for real app when launching
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .addTestDevice("CC5F2C72DF2B356BBF0DA198")
            .build();
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: But as I said, It has happened, and i clicked them accidentally so will it pose a threat of suspension to my account and if it does what measures can i take to keep it from suspension?

Comment: i already said no..@SyedWajahatAli instead multiple times clicking if you not done.. if done, google suspends you and no way to recover your account. Once lost is lost. However google give an appeal for your reason to fill a form to reveal. But possibilities to recover is 99.9% chance is very less. So don't do it is my suggestion especially incase of google. Read all policies google mentioned.

Comment: Right now it is not suspended do you know how long and when will google take action to suspend my account if they found out that i clicked? Or is it that they have not noticed it yet?

Comment: immediately will suspend :) @SyedWajahatAli and you will get mail that google suspended your admob account.so hope more than hour no suspension, so cool..no worries :)

Comment: Thanks after this comment I am gonna accept your answer as this was i wanted to ask and hear ofcourse. :)